# How to write a loop that adds all the numbers from the list into a variable

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a total beginner, self-learner and I'm trying to solve the problem 5 from **How to Think Like a Computer Scientist: Learning with Python 3**. The problem looks like this:

> xs = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
>
> Write a loop that adds all the numbers from the list into a variable called total. You should set the total variable to have the value 0 before you start adding them up, and print the value in total after the loop has completed.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
for xs in [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]:
    xs = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
    total = 0
total = sum(xs)
print(total)
```

Should I use a `for` loop at all? Or should I use a `sum` function?

Comment: Using `sum` is definitely preferred when you're coding, but the point of the exercise is to learn something, thus you should follow the instructions. Now, your `for` statement is good, however, think of what happens on every iteration. Try printing the value of `xs` for every iteration of the loop and see what it is. Then think about **where** do you want to *initialize* the `total` variable. You should loop over the variables and add them to the `total`, presumably one value at a time for every iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, indentation is very important in python. The code you posted above will throw an IndentationError. Be mindful what you want to have inside loops (indented) and what not.

Comment: ohhh i see, no need for a for loop as you mentioned. Yeah i got 301 in every iteration, when i only have to have 1. And i thought about where to initialize total from the problem itself. Isn't always the question itself a kind of an algorithm to your solution? i've read the question 20 times i know what to do, but to express it in code, gets tricky. Time will show i suppose. Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a for loop here simply:

```
xs = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]
total = sum(xs)
print(total)
```

If you really want to use a loop:

```
total = 0
xs = [12, 10, 32, 3, 66, 17, 42, 99, 20]

for i in xs:
    total += i
print(total)
```